# Can't draw a polyline via MapKit in Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm trying to draw a line between two annotations on my map. The code is working, but i don't see it on map. Here is my code:

```
func longPressGesture()
{
    let lpg = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressAction:")
    lpg.minimumPressDuration = 1;
    Map.addGestureRecognizer(lpg)
}

func longPressAction(myRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    let currPoint = myRecognizer.locationInView(Map)
    let point = Map.convertPoint(currPoint, toCoordinateFromView: Map)
    points.append(currPoint);
    if(points.count>1)
    {
        let startPoint = Map.convertPoint(points[points.count-2], toCoordinateFromView: Map)
        let endPoint = Map.convertPoint(currPoint, toCoordinateFromView: Map)
        var lineCoords = [startPoint,endPoint]
        var line = MKPolyline(coordinates: &lineCoords, count: 2)
        Map.addOverlay(line)
    }
    let myAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation();
    myAnnotation.coordinate = point
    myAnnotation.title = "Test"
    myAnnotation.subtitle = "Test subtitle"
    Map.addAnnotation(myAnnotation);
}
```

mapView method(not sure if it is used, i'm new to swift and i didn't write this):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    print(overlay)
    if overlay is MKCircle {
        let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        circle.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor();
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1);
        circle.lineWidth = 1;
        return circle;
    }else  if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
        let carte_Renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        carte_Renderer.alpha = 1
        return carte_Renderer
    }else if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay);
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5;
        return polylineRenderer;
    }else {
        return MKPolylineRenderer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you've got an `rendererForOverlay` method, which defines how your `MKPolyline` objects will look.

You'll need to include the`MKMapViewDelegate` as well for this to work.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer!
{
    if overlay is MKPolyline
    {
        let route: MKPolyline = overlay as MKPolyline
        let routeRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline:route)
        routeRenderer.lineWidth = 3.0
        routeRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1);

        return routeRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: added mapView method to the question

Comment: Have you got the `MKMapViewDelegate` there, can you show us your `Map` class declaration? Is your `rendererForOverlay` getting called?

Comment: delegate was remmed out, i don't know why :) 
unreeled it and everything worked, thank you!